# Replace multiple values in Outlook mail htmlbody

Tags: vba, outlook

I am using an .oft (Outlook template) file containing various placeholders. I want to replace the placeholders with strings

The place holders in the oft file are:

Dear ~emp~
~awd~

I am using the code below for replacements:

```
.htmlbody = Vtemplatebody
'replacing Dear with Dear Name, name in Column A
strFind = "Dear ~emp~"
strNew = "Dear " & ws.Cells(i, "f")
.htmlbody = Replace(.htmlbody, strFind, strNew)

'Replace award
strFind1 = "~awd~"
strNew1 = ws.Cells(i, "h")
.htmlbody = Replace(.htmlbody, strFind1, strNew1)
```

The first replacement viz ~emp~ is happening corrrectly ie the string is being replaced with the value in ws.Cells(i, "f"). But the second viz ~awd~ is not getting replaced with the value in the strNew1.

Is there something wrong in what I am doing or is it to be done some other way?

Comment: Maybe strNew1 is not coming across as a string?  Force with ```"" & ws.Cells(i, "h")```

Answer (score 0):

Have you run this code?  If so where?  I would expect the compiler to convert `.htmlbody` to `.HtmlBody`.

You give us too little of the code to be sure but I suspect wildcards. With the Replace **method**, asterisk (*), question mark (?) and tilde (~) are wild cards.  It is supposed to be the same for the Replace **function** but I cannot get any of these wild cards to work with the function.

You could try adding the following statements:

```
Vtemplatebody = Replace(Vtemplatebody,"~emp~","xxx")
Vtemplatebody = Replace(Vtemplatebody,"~awd~","yyy")
Debug.Print Vtemplatebody
```

In these statements "xxx" and "yyy" represent the values in `ws.Cells(i, "f")` and `ws.Cells(i, "h")`.  These statements will allow you to try different replaces and see the effect in the Immediate Window.  With statements like these, it is easy to try different values and home on some subtle problem which will be obvious once found.

Another option is to replace tilde with percent. Percent is not a wild card so using it as the delimiter would remove any possibility that wild cards are the problem.

How many of these substitutions are required.  Your approach is fine with one or two substitutions but becomes hard work with many substitutions.  I can show you a better technique if this would be helpful.

Comment: Sorry for the delay in responding. I did make changes on the lines suggested by you. I am curious to see the better technique in case there are multiple substitutions. Thanks.

Comment: i could make it work by using the ActiveInspector object.

Comment: Looking forward to the better technique you have mentioned.

Comment: @user1955215.  I thought I had added a comment pointing at my new answer but apparently not.  My second answer describes five different approaches all of which I use when appropriate.

Answer (score 0):

Most programming tasks can be solved by several different approaches.  How do you choose which is the best approach for any given task?

If you are writing a transaction processor that will process millions of transactions a day, every microsecond of processing time saved is valuable.  It can be worth hours of the programmer’s time to make the process marginally faster.  However, if you are writing a transaction processor, choosing VBA would be your first mistake.  VBA is not a slow as some people think but it designed to be easy to write rather than fast to execute.  For a macro that will only be executed once a day or for which any slowness is hidden behind user entry, minimising programmer's effort is the priority.

One algorithm may be more efficient than another.  I consider choosing the most appropriate algorithm to be a design decision rather than a programming decision.

When measuring programmer time, you need to consider:

- How long it will take the original programmer to write and debug the code.
- How long it will take a maintenance programmer to understand the code.
- How long it will take a maintenance programmer to update and debug the code to address a new requirement.

I sometimes see code that I think is clever, but which is difficult to understand.  How long did it take the original programmer to get right?  How long will it take every maintenance programmer to understand what the code does?  Very little code is written once and never updated.  Requirements can change and the code must be reviewed and updated.

Consider:

```
strFind = "Dear ~emp~"                           '
strNew = "Dear " & ws.Cells(i, "f")              ' Your code
.htmlbody = Replace(.htmlbody, strFind, strNew)  '

strFind = "~emp~"                                ' The code a maintenance
strNew = ws.Cells(i, "f")                        ' programmer
.htmlbody = Replace(.htmlbody, strFind, strNew)  ' might expect
```

Why do you included "Dear " in both the first find and new value but do nothing similar for the second find and new value?  If there is a reason, add a comment otherwise every maintenance programmer will spend time wondering why.  Eventually someone will remove the `"Dear "`.  If the `"Dear "` was important, this will lead to problems later.

What is in columns "f" and "h" of the worksheet?  In this case it may not matter.  The maintenance programmer is unlikely to be amending the code without looking at the worksheet and there is probably only one reference to each column in the code.  It becomes a problem when there are lots of columns and lots of references to those columns.  Many years ago, I was the maintenance programmer for some code with many references to columns 5 and 6.  For reasons above my paygrade, these two columns were swapped.  Every “5” in the code which was a reference to a column had to be replaced by “6” and every “6” in the code which was a reference to a column had to be replaced by “5”.  It was a nightmare particularly as there were lots of other 5s and 6s in the code.  I avoid literals in code.  I prefer something like:

```
Const ColSalutation As String = “f”
:          :          :          :          :
strNew = ws.Cells(i, ColSalutation).Value
```

This has two advantages: (1) if the column position changes, one amendment to the code and all references to the column have changed and (2) a meaningful name, such as ColSalutation, makes the code much easier to read.

Consider:

```
strFind1 = "~awd~"
strNew1 = ws.Cells(i, "h")
.htmlbody = Replace(.htmlbody, strFind1, strNew1)
```

Why `strFind1` and `strNew1`?  The values in `strFind` and `strNew` will not be required again so these variables are available for use.  If there is a reason, document it to avoid worrying the maintenance programmer.

Why not: `.htmlbody =`Replace(.htmlbody, "~awd~", ws.Cells(i, "h"))`?

There are situations in which I believe moving values to temporary variables makes the code clearer.  I am not sure it makes the code clearer here.

Below I introduce five subroutines showing different approaches to your requirement.  I offer suggestions as to when each approach might be the most appropriate.

I believe the easiest approach would be to create a new macro-enabled workbook with two worksheets: “Data” and “Replace”.  The macro `Prepare` will place the values in the worksheets expected by the other macros.

```
Sub Prepare()

  With Worksheets("Data")
    .Range("F5:I5").Value = Array("Jane", DateSerial(2020, 2, 1), 100, TimeSerial(12, 0, 0))
    .Range("G5").NumberFormat = "dddd mmmm d, yyyy"
    .Range("H5").NumberFormat = "$#,##0.00"
    .Range("I5").NumberFormat = "h:mm"
    .Columns.AutoFit
  End With
  With Worksheets("Replace")
    .Range("A1:B1").Value = Array("Original Value", "Column")
    .Range("A2:B2").Value = Array("%emp%", "f")
    .Range("A3:B3").Value = Array("%awd%", "h")
    .Range("A4:B4").Value = Array("%xyz%", "g")
    .Range("A5:B5").Value = Array("%uvw%", "i")
    .Columns.AutoFit
  End With

End Sub
```

Macro `Approach1` is based on your approach:

```
Sub Approach1()

  Dim HtmlBody As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Dim strFind As String
  Dim strNew As String

  Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
  i = 5
  HtmlBody = "<body>Dear %emp%<p>I am pleased to inform you of an award of " & _
             "<b>%awd%</b> which you will receive on %xyz% at %uvw%.<p>Yours<p>" & _
             "John Doe</body>  "

  strFind = "Dear %emp%"
  strNew = "Dear " & ws.Cells(i, "f")
  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, strFind, strNew)

  strFind = "%awd%"
  strNew = ws.Cells(i, "h")
  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, strFind, strNew)

  strFind = "%xyz%"
  strNew = ws.Cells(i, "g")
  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, strFind, strNew)

  strFind = "%uvw%"
  strNew = ws.Cells(i, "i")
  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, strFind, strNew)

  Debug.Print HtmlBody

End Sub
```

With this subroutine, and all subsequent ones, I have started with some code to initialise the variables that are initialised before your snippet of code.  I have followed my own advice and replace tilde with percent.  I have also increased the number of replacements from two to four.  The display values in the worksheet are:

```
Row|  F |             G           |   H   |  I  |
   |----+-------------------------+-------+-----|
  5|Jane|Saturday February 1, 2020|$100.00|12:00|
   |----+-------------------------+-------+-----|
```

With approach 1, three new statements are required per replacement.  It is easy enough to duplicate the last replacement and then amend the copy for the new replacement.  It is also easy to make mistakes amending the copy and often difficult to spot those mistakes.  The limit on the number of replacements with this approach is a personal choice but I do not like this approach and my limit is two or three.

Approach 2 is almost the same except I have not used temporary variables:

```
Sub Approach2()

  Dim HtmlBody As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
  i = 5
  HtmlBody = "<body>Dear %emp%<p>I am pleased to inform you of an award of " & _
             "<b>%awd%</b> which you will receive on %xyz% at %uvw%.<p>Yours<p>" & _
             "John Doe</body>  "

  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, "%emp%", ws.Cells(i, "f").Text)
  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, "%awd%", ws.Cells(i, "h").Text)
  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, "%xyz%", ws.Cells(i, "g").Text)
  HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, "%uvw%", ws.Cells(i, "i").Text)

  Debug.Print HtmlBody

End Sub
```

For approach 2, I have compressed your three statements into one.  If I can achieve something like this where the differences are easy to see and review, my limit on the number of replacements is a lot higher.

Note, the “.Text”.  You just specify the cell, for example: ws.Cells(i, "f").  This means you get the default property for a cell which is “Value”.  The Value property is fine for strings but for numbers and date you get the unformatted value.  For times, you get the number that Excel or Outlook uses to represent the time.  The Text property gives you the display value.  Compare the output from macros `Approach1` and `Approach2` to see what I mean.

With approach 3, I load the values for each replace into an array and then loop over the array.  The key statement is:

```
OrigValuesAndCols = Array("%emp%", "f", _
                          "%awd%", "h", _
                          "%xyz%", "g", _
                          "%uvw%", "i")
```

`OrigValuesAndCols` is a Variant.  The function `Array` effectively converts it to an array with eight elements.  Each pair of elements is a find value and a column number.  I have written a loop which extracts the four pairs and performs each of the four replacements in turn.  If you are unfamiliar with `Variants` and or the function `Array`, this approach may require careful study before you understand it.  That careful study will repay itself because this is a powerful technique that I use frequently.  I will say more when I describe approach 4.

```
Sub Approach3()

  Dim Col As String
  Dim HtmlBody As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Inx As Long
  Dim OrigValuesAndCols As Variant
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
  i = 5
  HtmlBody = "<body>Dear %emp%<p>I am pleased to inform you of an award of " & _
             "<b>%awd%</b> which you will receive on %xyz% at %uvw%.<p>Yours<p>" & _
             "John Doe</body>  "

  OrigValuesAndCols = Array("%emp%", "f", _
                            "%awd%", "h", _
                            "%xyz%", "g", _
                            "%uvw%", "i")

  For Inx = LBound(OrigValuesAndCols) To UBound(OrigValuesAndCols) Step 2
    Col = OrigValuesAndCols(Inx + 1)
    HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, OrigValuesAndCols(Inx), ws.Cells(i, Col).Text)
  Next

  Debug.Print HtmlBody

End Sub
```

Approach 4 is like approach 3 but I have created two arrays:

```
OrigValues = VBA.Array("%emp%", "%awd%", "%xyz%", "%uvw%")
NewValues = VBA.Array(ws.Cells(i, "f").Text, ws.Cells(i, "h").Text, _
                      ws.Cells(i, "g").Text, ws.Cells(i, "i").Text)
```

The function `VBA.Array` guarantees the lower bound of the array is 0.  With the function `Array`, the default lower bound is 0 but the `Option Base statement` can change it to 1.  I have never seen anyone use the `Option Base statement` but, if the lower bound **could** change, I use the function `LBound` to get the lower bound.  With approach 4, my loop statement is: `For Inx = 0 To UBound(NewValues)` because I know the lower bound must be zero.  With approach 3, my loop statement was: `For Inx = LBound(OrigValuesAndCols) To UBound(OrigValuesAndCols) Step 2`.  I have allowed for the lower bound to change.  The `Step 2` means each repeat of the loop steps `Inx` by 2.

With approach 3, the second value of each pair is the column code and the replace statement converts this to a cell reference.  With approach 4, array NewValues contains the cell display values.  Using column codes in one approach and cell display values in the other, shows that I can.  I think using column codes makes the array marginally easier to understand but you may disagree.  I sometimes find one array easier and sometimes I find two arrays easier.  I find one array easier most of the time because it is easier to check the two elements of a pair match.  With two arrays it can be difficult to check OrigValues(20) and NewValues(20) match.

```
Sub Approach4()

  Dim HtmlBody As String
  Dim i As Long
  Dim Inx As Long
  Dim NewValues As Variant
  Dim OrigValues As Variant
  Dim ws As Worksheet

  Set ws = Worksheets("Data")
  i = 5
  HtmlBody = "<body>Dear %emp%<p>I am pleased to inform you of an award of " & _
             "<b>%awd%</b> which you will receive on %xyz% at %uvw%.<p>Yours<p>" & _
             "John Doe</body>  "

  OrigValues = VBA.Array("%emp%", "%awd%", "%xyz%", "%uvw%")
  NewValues = VBA.Array(ws.Cells(i, "f").Text, ws.Cells(i, "h").Text, _
                        ws.Cells(i, "g").Text, ws.Cells(i, "i").Text)

  For Inx = 0 To UBound(NewValues)
    HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, OrigValues(Inx), NewValues(Inx))
  Next

  Debug.Print HtmlBody

End Sub
```

Both approach 3 and approach 4 can be used for a reasonable number of replacement but they can become awkward.  They also have the disadvantage that any change must be made by the programmer.  For approach 5, I have added a new worksheet “Replace” with values:

```
Row|       A      |   B  |
   |--------------+------|
  1|Original Value|Column|
   |--------------+------|
  2|%emp%         |f     |
   |--------------+------|
  3|%awd%         |h     |
   |--------------+------|
  4|%xyz%         |g     |
   |--------------+------|
  5|%uvw%         |i     |
   |--------------+------|
```

I am sometimes surprised when I see code building arrays which could more easily have been created in a worksheet and then loaded to an array.  The number of replaces is only limited by the number of rows per worksheet and the user can maintain this table if necessary.

With this worksheet approach, the code becomes:

```
Sub Approach5()

  Dim ColData As String
  Dim HtmlBody As String
  Dim NewValue As String
  Dim OrigValue As String
  Dim RowData As Long
  Dim RowRplcCrnt As Long
  Dim RowRplcLast As Long
  Dim wsData As Worksheet
  Dim wsRplc As Worksheet

  Set wsData = Worksheets("Data")
  Set wsRplc = Worksheets("Replace")
  RowData = 5
  HtmlBody = "<body>Dear %emp%<p>I am pleased to inform you of an award of " & _
             "<b>%awd%</b> which you will receive on %xyz% at %uvw%.<p>Yours<p>" & _
             "John Doe</body>  "

  With wsRplc
    RowRplcLast = .Cells(, Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
  End If

  For RowRplcCrnt = 2 To rowrpllast
    With wsRplc
      OrigValue = .Cells(RowRplcCrnt, 1).Value
      ColData = .Cells(RowRplcCrnt, 2).Value
    End With
    NewValue = ws.Cells(RowData, Col).Text
    HtmlBody = Replace(HtmlBody, OrigValue, NewValue)
  Next

  Debug.Print HtmlBody

End Sub
```

I have used every one of these approaches in an operational macro.  None of them is the best approach in every case.  I hope you can understand how I select the best approach for each problem.  The key question is: which approach will be easiest for the original programmer to create and document and which all future maintenance programmers will understand as easily as possible.